# What's the correct way to store a time interval in Core Data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsdatecomponents, nstimeinterval

I need to store a time interval in an app's database that will be added occasionally to `NSDate`. Problem is, I don't know what data type to choose for it. Some people advise to store `NSTimeInterval`, but will it cause miscalculations when user's timezone changes? Maybe it's better to store `NSDateComponents` (as a "Transformable" data type) or is there another better way to do it?

Comment: It depends. A time interval of 10 seconds, 20 minutes or 3 hours is 10 seconds, 20*60 seconds or 3*3600 seconds, no matter what the time zone or the current date is, and you can store it as an NSTimeInterval. – A time interval of "1 day" can be 23, 24, or 25 hours. A time interval of "1 month" can be 28, 29, 30, or 31 days (in the Gregorian calendar).

Comment: @MartinR Yeah, forgot to mention that. Intervals in my app may be either a few minutes or several months

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A minute is 60 seconds, and an hour is 3600 seconds, no matter what the
current date, time zone or calendar is. If you want to store the duration "24 hours" then you can store it as a time interval with the value 24*3600.

All larger units, starting with *day,* must be interpreted according to
the current date, time zone and calendar. The duration "one day" can be
23, 24, or 25 hours in regions with daylight savings time.
In particular, "24 hours" and "1 day" have a different meaning.
The duration "1 month" can be from 28 to 31 days in the Gregorian 
calendar, and "1 year" can be 365 or 366 days. Other calendars may have
other "peculiarities".

Therefore all durations involving "day" or larger units must be stored
as date components. Transforming to `NSDateComponents` is one possibility,
alternatively you can add multiple properties "durationDays",
"durationMonths", etc to your Core Data entity. This has the advantage
that the values can be referred to in fetch requests or sort
descriptors.

Comment: Thank you for good explanation. I guess I'll use multiple properties for that.